# Password protect s3 bucket with lambda function in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

**I added website authentication for s3 bucket using lambda function** and then connect the lambda function with the CloudFront by using behavior settings in distribution settings and it worked fine and added authentication(means htaccess authentication in simple servers). Now I want to change the password for my website authentication. For that, I updated the password and published the new version of the lambda function and then in the distribution settings; I created a new invalidation to clear cache. But it didn't work, and website authentication password didn't change. Below is my lambda function code to add authentication.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  // Get request and request headers
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const headers = request.headers;

  // Configure authentication
  const authUser = 'user';
  const authPass = 'pass';

  // Construct the Basic Auth string
  const authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authUser + ':' + authPass).toString('base64');

  // Require Basic authentication
  if (typeof headers.authorization == 'undefined' || headers.authorization[0].value != authString) {
      const body = 'Unauthorized';
      const response = {
        status: '401',
        statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
        },
      };
     callback(null, response);
  }

    // Continue request processing if authentication passed
     callback(null, request);
};
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you lambda suppose to be deployed to Lambda@Edge (us-east-1). Not sure about backet...

Comment: Can you please explain me, How?

Answer (score 0):

On Lambda function view, After you save your changes (using Firefox could be a safer option, see below if you wonder why)

you will see a menu item under Configuration - > Designer -> CloudFront. You will see following screens.

[image]

[image]

After you deploy :

[image]

You can publish your change to CloudFront distribution. Once you  publish this, it will automatically start deploying CF distribution which you can view on CF menu.

Also i would prefer using "Viewer Request" as a CloudFront trigger event, not sure which one you are using as this should avoid Cloudfront caching. On top of this Chrome sometimes fails to save changes on Lambda. There should be a bug on aws console. Try Firefox just to be safe when you are editing lambda functions.